# assign data(i) into std_logic_vector(0 downto 0) in vhdl

Tags: vector, vhdl, type-conversion

I have the following problem:

My code has this constant value

```
constant source_vector : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "1011000";
```

This value needs to be fed into a signal of type std_logic_vector, bit by bit. The problem is that the destination vector has a size defined in a constant. For the test, I am using size 1.

```
constant k : integer := 1;
dest_vector : in std_logic_vector(k-1 downto 0);
```

When I try to assign the first bit:

```
dest_vector <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(source_vector(0), k));
```

I got this error:
ERROR: [VRFC 10-925] indexed name is not a natural

I have tried several things, but no luck. Perhaps I am missing something... Any advice here?

Comment: Use `dest_vector <= source_vector(0 downto 0);` which uses a slice name or `dest_vector(0) <= source_vector(0);` which uses indexed names for both target and right hand side. There's also `dest_vector <= "" & source_vector(0);` which derives the type of the concatenation result from context while concatenating a null array to a value of the element type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names, 8.5 Slice names, 9.2.5 Adding operators ("&") and 12.5 The context of overload resolution
 (which "&").

Comment: For your original expression there is no function `to_unsigned` found in package numeric_std that has the signature [std_ulogic, natural **return** unsigned]. A value with a base type of std_ulogic isn't implicitly convertible to type natural (to_unsigned[natural, natural **return** unsigned]). See 4.10 Conformance rules.

Comment: So that question is: why are you using `to_unsigned`?

Comment: Thanks to the info and references, @user1155120. The `(0 downto 0)` worked fine, also indexing the destination. I was using `to_unsigned` as the normal assignment was not working, and the compiler message implied that the value for an indexing should be an integer, and one thing led to another... The main problem was assigning a value of one bit, but in a form of a vector of size one.

Comment: For the knowledgeable VHDL aficionado `dest_vector <= "" & source_vector(0);` may express the problem being addressed more clearly. Also see 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges for the definition of null array, *compatible*, and *satisfies*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from user1155120 Jul 16 '17 at 19:47

Use `dest_vector <= source_vector(0 downto 0);` which uses a slice name or `dest_vector(0) <= source_vector(0);` which uses indexed names for both target and right hand side. There's also `dest_vector <= "" & source_vector(0);` which derives the type of the concatenation result from context while concatenating a null array to a value of the element type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names, 8.5 Slice names, 9.2.5 Adding operators ("&") and 12.5 The context of overload resolution (which "&").